# Get the next upcoming Friday at 5 PM

Tags: momentjs

I need to display how far away a deadline is that is every Friday at 5PM. Moment will give me that date for a day of the week, but it's always the current time, so the deadline always displays 'x days, 23 hours, 59 minutes'. How do I get the day, AND a specific time from moment? In my example, I need deadline to be 'next Friday, at 17:00' instead of 'next Friday, at the current time'

```js
console.log(timeLeft());

function timeLeft() {
  var dayINeed = 5; // for Friday

  var deadline;

  // if we haven't yet passed the day of the week that I need:
  if (moment().isoWeekday() <= dayINeed) {
    // then just give me this week's instance of that day
    deadline = moment().isoWeekday(dayINeed);
  } else {
    // otherwise, give me next week's instance of that day
    deadline = moment().add(1, 'weeks').isoWeekday(dayINeed);
  }
  console.log(deadline);
  const now = moment();
  const days = deadline.diff(now, 'days');
  const hours = deadline.subtract(days, 'days').diff(now, 'hours');
  const minutes = deadline.subtract(hours, 'hours').diff(now, 'minutes');
  return `${days} days, ${hours} hours, and ${minutes} minutes`;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set to `deadline` the time (17:00), instead of getting current time, you can use moment [`startOf()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) and [`set()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/set/), simply add the following to your code:

```
deadline.startOf('day').set({h: 17});
```

This way you are setting `17:00:00` to `deadline` and you will get the desired output.

Here a full example:

```js
console.log(timeLeft());

function timeLeft() {
  var dayINeed = 5; // for Friday

  var deadline;

  // if we haven't yet passed the day of the week that I need:
  if (moment().isoWeekday() <= dayINeed) {
    // then just give me this week's instance of that day
    deadline = moment().isoWeekday(dayINeed);
  } else {
    // otherwise, give me next week's instance of that day
    deadline = moment().add(1, 'weeks').isoWeekday(dayINeed);
  }
  deadline.startOf('day').set({h: 17});
  console.log(deadline.format());
  const now = moment();
  const days = deadline.diff(now, 'days');
  const hours = deadline.subtract(days, 'days').diff(now, 'hours');
  const minutes = deadline.subtract(hours, 'hours').diff(now, 'minutes');
  return `${days} days, ${hours} hours, and ${minutes} minutes`;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.js"></script>
```

If you want, you can use setter like [`hour()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/hour/), [`minute()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/minute/) etc to set `17:00:00` to `deadline`.